# Filtrar un array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

Tengo esta respuesta de una llamada:

```
 let filteredList = [...datosApi];
```

donde datosApi es:

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Monte 12",
  "description": "Monte 12",
  "price": 70,
  "totalCredits": 222,
  "stockCredits": 222,
  "latitude": "-54",
  "longitude": "-54",
  "age": 4,
  "frame": 1125,
  "size": 10,
  "cadastre": "sd",
  "creationDate": "2022-11-18",
  "updatedDate": "2022-11-18",
  "active": true,
  "categoryId": 1,
  "category": "C1",
  "forestTypeId": 1,
  "forestType": "PINO",
  "providerId": 1,
  "sustainabilityGoalDtoList": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "color": "#e5233d",
      "position": 1,
      "name": "Fin de la pobreza",
      "desc": "Fin de la pobreza"
    }
  ],
  "productImageDtoList": []
}
```

Estoy intentando hacer varios filtros, de la siguiente manera:

**data = [stateCheckcategory, stateCheckforest, stateCheckcountry, stateCheckdevelopment];**

donde
stateCheckdevelopment es:

```
[
  {
    "susDev": "Fin de la pobreza",
    "check": false
  },
  {
    "susDev": "Hambre cero",
    "check": false
  }
]
```

He creado las siguientes variables para solo coger la que esta en check.

```
  let categories = data[0].filter(c => c.check).map(c => c.category);
    let forestType = data[1].filter(c => c.check).map(c => c.forestType);
    let country = data[2].filter(c => c.check).map(c => c.country);
    let development = data[3].filter(c => c.check).map(c => c.susDev);
```

y con esto voy filtrando la **filteredList**, la respuesta a la llamada de todos los datos.
En todos los casos me funciona, menos en el caso de development, ya que esa parte es un array bidimensional. Estoy haciendo lo mismo en todos los casos, pero en ese no me funciona, como podria filtrarlo bien??

```
if (development.length > 0) {
      filteredList = filteredList.filter((c) => development.includes(c.sustainabilityGoalDtoList["name"]));
      ) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí estas intentando extraer `name` de `sustainabilityGoalDtoList` lo puedes solucionar de la siguiente manera:

**JS**

```
datosApi.forEach((item, index) => {
    console.log(item.sustainabilityGoalDtoList[index].name)
})
```

Si colocas `console.log(item.sustainabilityGoalDtoList)` te devuelve un array por lo tanto no puedes acceder a name así simplemente.

El `forEach` cuenta con ciertos [parámetros](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) y uno de esos es el **index** `forEach((item, index)` entonces utilizaremos el index para acceder el array resultante de cada iteración, accedemos al primer array `item.sustainabilityGoalDtoList[index]` que viene siendo el **index 0** y una vez dentro de ese array puedes acceder a `name` = `item.sustainabilityGoalDtoList[index].name`.

**JSON**

```
const datosApi = [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Monte 12",
        "description": "Monte 12",
        "price": 70,
        "totalCredits": 222,
        "stockCredits": 222,
        "latitude": "-54",
        "longitude": "-54",
        "age": 4,
        "frame": 1125,
        "size": 10,
        "cadastre": "sd",
        "creationDate": "2022-11-18",
        "updatedDate": "2022-11-18",
        "active": true,
        "categoryId": 1,
        "category": "C1",
        "forestTypeId": 1,
        "forestType": "PINO",
        "providerId": 1,
        "sustainabilityGoalDtoList": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "color": "#e5233d",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "Fin de la pobreza",
            "desc": "Fin de la pobreza"
          }
        ],
        "productImageDtoList": []
      }
]
```